# Is the Franke-Wolfe algorithm the same as Manifold optimization?

Tags: optimization, geometry, information-geometry

The [Frank-Wolfe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank%E2%80%93Wolfe_algorithm) optimization algorithm describes optimization over a constrained domain. 
In the Manifold Optimization literature (e.g. [1]) a Gradient-Step is done using an [exponential map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_(Riemannian_geometry)). This maps takes account of both the gradient and the manifold constraint.

I thus ask: can the Frank-Wolfe algorithm be seen as an instance of Manifold Optimization?

[1] Absil, P-A., Robert Mahony, and Rodolphe Sepulchre. Optimization algorithms on matrix manifolds. Princeton University Press, 2009.

Comment: If you constrain the manifold to be a compact, convex set, which manifolds don't have to be (e.g., consider a Klein bottle), I suppose you could consider F-W optimization, and any other optimization method that works on compact convex sets, to be special cases of manifold optimization, but I don't see that that gains you anything.